# Detectar círculo en imagen binaria de contornos en Python

Tags: python, imagen, opencv

Tengo la siguiente imagen de 0's y 1's y me gustaría saber cómo puedo detectar que lo de dentro es un círculo. He probado con cv.HoughCircle pero pero me detecta un NoneType Object.

```
circles = cv.HoughCircles(cmoneda, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, minDist=1, minRadius=int(rrange[0]), maxRadius=int(rrange[1]))
```

Las imágenes que me detecta el programa son casi igual que en la de esta interacción.

Uso como radio las dimensiones de la imagen, la minDist en HoughCircles la distancia entre centros de los círculos (he puesto 1 porque siempre va a haber 1 en la imagen). El parametro dp indica la resolución (1 si es la misma que la imagen original).

Por si alguno supiera otro método también me serviría. Muchas gracias por los aportes.

[image: cmoneda]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Teoría preliminar

La transformada de Hough implementada en OpenCV opera en tres fases:

1. Detecta bordes en la imagen (aplicando un filtro Canny)
2. Transforma cada punto de la imagen en un conjunto de puntos en un espacio alternativo
3. Cuenta en el espacio alternativo cuántas intersecciones se producen, y eso representa candidatos a posibles círculos de la imagen

(En realidad es algo más complejo lo que hace, pero para entender bien los parámetros que hay que pasarle, esta explicación en tres fases es más conveniente).

#### Detección de bordes

Para esta imagen de entrada:

[image: Entrada]

El filtro de Canny con umbral mínimo 150 y máximo 300 daría esta imagen de bordes:

[image: Bordes]

La pongo solo como orientación, para aplicar Hough no necesitas encontrar primero esta imagen pues la función `HoughCircles()` se ocupa de llamar internamente al filtro de Canny, pero sí que tendrás que especificarle como parámetro `param1` el umbral máximo a utilizar (como mínimo usará la mitad)

#### La transformación a un espacio alternativo

La transformada de Hough crea un "espacio alternativo" tridimensional en el que representar los parámetros de posibles círculos, de modo que en ese espacio un eje representa el tamaño (radio) del círculo, y otros dos ejes representan las coordenadas c_x, c_y, de su centro.

Cada pixel blanco `(x,y)` de la imagen de bordes da lugar a una "superficie" (un cono) en la transformada de Hough, que correspondería a todos los radios y centros de los círculos que pasarían por ese punto `(x,y)`. Si dos puntos blancos de la imagen están en un mismo círculo, los dos conos correspondientes de la transformada de Hough se intersectarán. A medida que más y más puntos blancos de la imagen de bordes pertenezcan a un mismo círculo, más y más conos intersectarán en un mismo punto 3D en el espacio transformado.

Lo que hace Hough es inicializar ese espacio 3D como una matriz de ceros. Las dimensiones de esa matriz serán iguales a las de tu imagen (cuando pones `dp=1`)

Después, por cada pixel blanco en la imagen de entrada (que es la imagen ya convertida a bordes), calcula los puntos 3D por los que pasa el cono resultado de la transformación, e incrementa en 1 cada uno de esos puntos.

Una vez ha hecho eso con todos los pixeles blancos de la entrada, en el espacio 3D transformado tendremos "constelaciones" por así decir. Elementos de la matriz que habrán obtenido un valor más que otros alto (porque muchos conos habrían "intersectado" en esos puntos).

Esos puntos "brillantes" del espacio transformado son los candidatos a círculos detectados en la imagen original. Las coordenadas 3D de esos puntos en la transformada nos darán los valores del radio y centro del círculo hallado.

Hacen falta por tanto más parámetros para determinar con qué "puntos brillantes" quedarse en el espacio transformado. Algunos de esos parámetros serían el radio máximo y mínimo que se quiere hallar, pero un parámetro muy importante es también **el umbral** del contador. Es decir, a partir de qué valor se considera que ese punto representa a un círculo de interés. O dicho de otra forma, cuántos pixeles blancos de la imagen de bordes consideraremos "dentro de un mismo círculo" para que sea detectado.

Un valor bajo de este parámetro detectará muchos "falsos positivos". Un valor muy alto hará que no se detecte nada si los círculos en la imagen de entrada no son muy perfectos.

Por desgracia la forma de hallar el valor apropiado para ese parámetro suele ser por ensayo y error, pues depende mucho de cuántos círculos y de qué calidad aparezcan en tu imagen de entrada.

He encontrado que para tu caso un valor apropiado parece ser `param2=20` (sorprendentemente bajo).

## Ejemplo

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('circulo.png', 0)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(img, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, minDist=1,
      param1=300, param2=20)
print(len(circles[0]))
```

Lo que retorna `circles` es un array numpy con un solo elemento `[0]` y dentro de él hay tantos elementos como círculos detectados en la imagen, ordenados de "más probable" a "menos probable" (ordenados en realidad por el valor de su contador en el espacio de Hough).

En el ejemplo anterior salen 207 candidatos, pero la mayoría son "falsos positivos" debido al borde irregular de la imagen de entrada. Basta quedarse con el primero de ellos, que es el "más probable".

Podemos pintarlo sobre la imagen de entrada, para verlo:

```
cimg = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
c = circles[0][0]
# Dibujar circulo en verde
cv.circle(cimg,(c[0],c[1]),c[2],(0,255,0),2)
# Dibujar centro, en rojo
cv.circle(cimg,(c[0],c[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```

El resultado en `cimg` es:

[image: Resultado]

## Ampliación

La imagen de entrada en este caso no es un círculo perfecto. Se aprecia bastante ruido en la zona inferior. Eso puede ser el causante de que haya que usar un umbral tan bajo como `param2=20`. Creo que la calidad de la detección puede mejorar mucho si se aplica un `medianBlur()` a la imagen de entrada. Por ejemplo:

```
img = cv.medianBlur(img, 35)
```

suaviza la entrada reduciendo el ruido. Ahora la imagen se ve así:

[image: Suavizada]

En este caso se puede aumentar el valor de `param2` hasta 80 para reducir los falsos positivos:

```
circles = cv.HoughCircles(img, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp = 1, minDist=1, 
           param1=300, param2=80)
print(len(circles[0]))
```

y salen solo 4 círculos de este modo.

Quedándonos de nuevo con el "mejor" (`circles[0][0]`) y pintándolo sobre la imagen original:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta funciona de maravilla! ¡Muy currada y muy bien explicada! @abulafia